# How to get the selected text from a system.web.mvc.selectlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a system.web.mvc.selectlist when I use .selectedvalue it gives me the value as expected however I use an int ID as the value and would like to get the display text instead.

Update
I've created a selectlist and I'd like to retrieve the selected text on the next line of code. I.e.

SelectList sl = new SelectList(items, "id", "name", 10);
String txt= sl.selectedvalue.text;

That last line is where I am stuck. I'm looking to get the name field for the item with id 10. Ideally without looking up in the db as I want a generic function I can use on all select lists.

Comment: Where do you want to get this display text? When you post back?

Comment: Can you please post example of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible since the text isn't passed back to the server in a post, only the value is. I can think of two ways to get it though:

- Query the database with the value to get the text.
- Set the text in a hidden field on the client side before posting the
  form. You can do this with jQuery for example.